# overload of session log in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I have a mappig to update certain columns in a table. Only 10% or less records should get updated. The remaining records should be rejected by the informatica.

The mapping works just fine if not for all the records getting logged into the session log file. Is there a way to prevent this other than using the filter transformation? I am aware this can be eliminated with a filter transforamtion. But just wanted to check if there is any simpler approach like selecting an option or something.

Answer (score 0):

Change the tracing level to `Terse` - you can configure it for the update strategy transformation transformation or for the entire session (`Config Object` / `Override tracing`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I do not want the rejected records to get logged into the session file. But if I select the option "Terse", it still logs in the rejected records right?

Comment: @shinysherbina No, the rejected rows will no longer be logged. There will only be a summary information about total number of rejected rows. Did you actually try to use this option?

Answer (score 0):

Well, by design, you should not let the reject the records and let them go to sink. Rather, control the logic for rejection, so that in future if there is a change to that rejection logic, you have control in ur hands.

Further, the rejected records are logged to session log by default, since its supposed to be abnormal behaviour on a mapping's part that some data is not handled properly through the flow.

To avoid getting all that data logged into session log, you can change the tracing level of the session to Terse. But remember, in that case, you wont get lot of other logging information in session, that is generally useful. This will achieve the end result, but is not the "ideal" way of achieving the same end result.

I would suggest looking again at your mapping design.